# SQL скрипт для определения фродового вызова в одно время из разных городов

Tags: sql

Ребята, привет!

Помогите пож-та разобраться, как корректно построить скрипт на SQL

Есть таблица совершенных абонентами звонков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как корректно найти все вызовы, совершенные в один день но из разных городов.
По ключу PK (User,Card,Calling_TIME)

То есть нужно из базы с милионнами записей найти фродовые вызовы, которые проходили в одно время из разных городов. Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Comment: Ответ я дал (с датами повозиться было полезно), но поясните, пожалуйста, почему сами не пишете код, если у вас задача за задачей по SQL идут? Я понимаю, регулярка в прошлый раз - достаточно в стороне стоящая вещь, но тут-то - обычный запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окончательный ответ с учетом объяснения в комментариях, что "Определением фрода является случай, когда один абонент за один день позвонил из разных городов. [...] Исключить только те звонки, когда абонент звонил только из одного города за один день."
И учитывая, что на Oracle у вас код предыдущий работал, я просто добавил сюда слово `DISTINCT` (преверил с ним на mySQL на чистом DATETIME  - звонки из одного города предсказуемо убираются).

За конкретный день будет ключ все же не с "Calling_TIME", а с (условно) "Calling_DATE".

**Код:**

```
SELECT id, User, card, DATE(calling_Time) AS Calling_DATE, City 
FROM calls
WHERE (User, card, DATE(calling_Time)) IN ((
    SELECT User, card, DATE(calling_Time)  
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY User, card, DATE(calling_Time)
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT City) > 1));
```

**Код с проверкой:**

```
CREATE TABLE calls(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user VARCHAR (25),
    card INT,
    calling_Time DATETIME,
    City VARCHAR (25)
);
INSERT INTO calls (user, card, calling_Time, City)
    VALUES
    (1, 1, '2018-05-25 21:25:54', 'Москва'),
    (2, 1, '2018-05-25 21:25:54', 'Самара'),
    (2, 1, '2018-05-25 21:25:54', 'Самара'),
    (1, 1, '2018-05-26 21:25:54', 'Москва'),
    (1, 1, '2018-05-25 21:25:54', 'Питер')
;
SELECT * FROM calls;

SELECT id, User, card, DATE(calling_Time) AS Calling_DATE, City 
FROM calls
WHERE (User, card, DATE(calling_Time)) IN ((
    SELECT User, card, DATE(calling_Time)  
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY User, card, DATE(calling_Time)
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT City) > 1));
```

**Вывод:**

```
Affected rows: 0

Affected rows: 5

Query result:
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| id | user | card | calling_Time        | City   |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Москва |
| 2  | 2    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Самара |
| 3  | 2    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Самара |
| 4  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-26 21:25:54 | Москва |
| 5  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Питер  |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
Affected rows: 5

Query result:
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| id | User | card | calling_Date        | City   |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25          | Москва |
| 5  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25          | Питер  |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
Affected rows: 2
```

Comment: Сергей,я посидел над скриптом, прежде чем писать сюда.

Задача стоит так - найти вызовы не за конкретную дату, а все фродовые вызовы в таблице (вызов совершенный в один день из разных городов) для всех абонентов. Тут вроде как оконными функциями можно закрыть это, но у меня не оплучилось.

В результирующий набор должны попасть все абоненты и все вызовы этих абонентов, которе совершались в один день из разных городов.

Comment: Не очень понимаю. Определением фрода у вас является случай, когда один абонент за один день позвонил из разных городов? И вы хотите вывести по такому критерию? (Т.е.исключить только те звонки, когда абонент звонил только из одного города за один день?)

Comment: Да, вы все верно описали, прямо в точку.
Из этого отчета я возьму:
count(кол-во звонков (звонков из города1 и фродовых звонков за этот же день из города 2)
Потом из этих звонков удалю звонки из города 1, оставив только фродовые - это вторая часть отчета, которую я планирую построить.
и 3- вытяну таких абонентов в отдельную таблицу для последующей проверки.

Звонки, которые совершались в один день из 1 города не лолжны попасть в выборку

Comment: Должно быть просто, я запрос за 15 минут написал. Только что-то странное с функцией DATE у меня - выясняю. И совершенно не вижу тут необходимости в оконных функциях.

Comment: Сергей, мне не кажется, что тут все просто)

Надо для связки PK (User,Card,Calling_TIME) вычислить фродовые звонки в один день но из разных городов. Я пока ума не приложу, как это можно сделать просто. Если сможете, буду очень признателен.
По поводу date - можно просто отрезать часы, минуты, секунды, к примеру to_date(calling_Time) или trunc(calling_Time) - это будет работать в качестве дня вызова.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138380/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: В очередной раз спасибо! Все отлично!